# How to disallow PUT while allowing POST and PATCH in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to completely disallow PUT for a repository in Spring Data REST while POST on the collection and PATCH on the item remain possible?

The rationale behind this is that a PUT typically allows for replace semantics, but in our case the resource can only be created via POST on the collection, partially updated via PATCH on the item (using specific UI dialogs... each of which only supports a particular partial update), or deleted via DELETE on the item.

Comment: I guess you checked the reference documentation as I did? Well, I couldn't find any hint on your issue. How about creating your own servlet filter?

Comment: Yes, I checked and could not find anything, too. I think this is worth a feature request. Allowed methods should be somehow customizable in Spring Data REST, aligned to the existing exclusion/exposure mechanism.

Comment: @SvenLudwig, did you end up using a servlet filter or did you find some other solution?

Comment: We removed Spring Data REST from our Spring stack, because it does not use secure defaults and actually represented a major security risk in our context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Spring security in your application, then this can be done by adding intercept-url to deny access to PUT method on Spring data repository, something like below:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/{repositoryPath}" method="PUT" access="denyAll" />
```