# Set disallowed fields in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I want to exclude certain fields from a POST to my repositories.

For example I want to set the version myself so users cannot set this field themselves.

For example in the class below.

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    private String name;
}
```

I have tried to use the `@ReadOnlyProperty` annotation and not having a setter for the version field. But nothing worked, users can still set the version fields themselves. I have also tried to implement a global initializer like below, but without success. The binder gets picked up though.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void globalBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
        webDataBinder.setDisallowedFields("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766067/how-to-disallow-put-while-allowing-post-and-patch-in-spring-data-rest
Refer to this post

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am asking. I don't want to not expose certain methods like PUT or DELETE, but to disallow the setting of certain exposed fields

Comment: A Jackson JSONView perhaps?

Comment: That seems like a good idea, but I think one cannot annotate a Repository which is annotated with "RepositoryRestResource" also with "JsonView". So I would have to write a controller for each repository, but then I can just remove the field manually myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place @JsonIgnore on field and on setter, and place @JsonProperty("propertyName") on getter.

Just tested - works for me:

```
@JsonIgnore
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDate lastUpdated;

@JsonProperty("lastUpdated")
public LocalDate getLastUpdated() {
    return lastUpdated;
}

@JsonIgnore
public void setLastUpdated(LocalDate lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}
```

Comment: I have marked this answer as correct. The only required thing is the `@JsonIgnore` on the setter field, the other annotations depend on your requirements. Thank you!