# Cannot make a field WRITE_ONLY in Spring Data Rest

Tags: jackson, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE and Spring Data Rest for a project in which I want a WRITE_ONLY password field. That is...you can perform a POST with this field set, and it will be deserialized and usable within an event handler annotated with `@HandleBeforeCreate`. However, this field will only ever be used on creation, and after that it should never show up anywhere, hence WRITE_ONLY. I have tried solutions like this...

```
public class Person {

  @JsonIgnore
  String password;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @JsonProperty("password")
  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
  }

}
```

and this...

```
public class Person {

  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  String password;

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
  }

}
```

but it seems like as soon as `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonProperty` make an appearance in any form or combination, Spring Data Rest stops deserializing the password field and I can no longer access it in my `@HandleBeforeCreate` annotated method.

This seems to contradict similar advice given here:

- [Set disallowed fields in Spring Data Rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506315/set-disallowed-fields-in-spring-data-rest)
- [Ignoring property when deserializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019834/ignoring-property-when-deserializing)

It also occurred to me that a projection could easily solve this problem, but it is my understanding that there is no way to provide a *default* projection for repositories, so the password field would show up unless a user included `?projection=noPassword` in their request, which is not what I want.

I just want to use the password field during creation via POST, and have it be utterly forgotten about afterwards, never to be rendered again.

Is a bug filing in order, or have I overlooked something?